# Partially update Document with Pyspark in CosmosDB with MongoDB API

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm using Azure Databricks with Pyspark and a CosmosDB with the MongoDB API.

The following Pyspark command is being used to store a `data_frame` in the CosmosDB which works fine:

```
def storeCollection(self, collection, data_frame, save_mode="append"):
data_frame.write.format(
        "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option(
        "spark.database.output.uri", self.uri).option(
        "spark.database.output.database", self.db).option(
        "spark.database.output.collection", collection).mode(save_mode).save()
```

But now my problem: I have the following Document structure in my CosmosDB:

```
{
 "_id" : "687c0184-aaa6-11e8-94bd-cba20d67390c",
 "api" : "",
 "aspectSet" : "",
 "id" : "687c0184-aaa6-11e8-94bd-cba20d67390c",
 "providerID" : "",
 "searchDate" : "",
 "searchQuery" : [
    {
        "_id" : "0",
        "id" : "0",
        "queryID" : "",
        "searchTerm" : "",
        "searchTermCategory" : "",
        "searchTermLanguage" : "en",
        "searchTermPriority" : "1",
        "searchTermSubcategory" : "",
        "weight" : "1"
    }
   ]
}
```

I want now to add a new `searchQuery` to the list of `searchQueries` by performing a partial update of the Document but I don't find any Examples on how to do it.

There is a page from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support) which says that CosmosDB supports a lot of the MongoDB features but I can't find any examples on how to do it.

Did someone already work with CosmosDB and faced a similar problem? Any suggestions or pointers would be highly appreciated.